# Not able to set the focus on a HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry

I am not able to set the focus on the `HorizontalFieldManager` having two `LabelFields`. I want to highlight the `HorizontalFieldManager` when it gets focus. I am using the following code, but it is not working.

```java
HorizontalFieldManager hrzMgrTimeLabel = new HorizontalFieldManager(
        Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT|Manager.FOCUSABLE) {

    protected void onFocus(int direction) {
        focussed = true;
        invalidate();
        super.onFocus(direction);
    }

    protected void onUnfocus() {
        focussed = false;
        invalidate();
        super.onUnfocus();
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setBackgroundColor(0x646060);
        if (focussed) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        g.clear();
        super.paint(g);
    }
};

hrzMgrTimeLabel.add(a);
hrzMgrTimeLabel.add(b);

horizontalFieldManager_left15.add(hrzMgrTimeLabel);
```

Here is the LabelField implementation.

```java
final LabelField a= new LabelField("") {
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x646060);
        graphics.clear();
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
};

final LabelField b= new LabelField("") {
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x646060);
        graphics.clear();
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
};
```

Comment: Update your question, you can use some image to explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I hve two labelfields having data like 7 in one and 0 in other which i am adding to HFM ,I want to have a focus on it .

Comment: When focused, do you need to change the background color of the HorizontalFieldManager?

Comment: ya,i want a focus on HFM but its nt

Answer (score 1):

The [`getFocusRect()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#getFocusRect%28net.rim.device.api.ui.XYRect%29) function might give you the answer.
It gives the extent for which the focus is applied in Manager and then the `Graphics.paint()` method or `Border` class can be used.

Comment: Can you please explain with a snippet applying to my code,i am not clear

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus your label field then use `final LabelField a= new LabelField("".FOCUSABLE)`.

Comment: I have added the label fields to HFM i want to focus the entire HFM

Comment: if i make both the labelfield focusable both are getting focussed but not as a whole,I am getting focus on each labelfield

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least one focusable field on the `HorizontalFieldManager`. The following line will do that.

```java
hrzMgrTimeLabel.add(new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE));
```

Check the following code.

```java
HorizontalFieldManager hrzMgrTimeLabel = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.FOCUSABLE) {
    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setBackgroundColor(isFocus() ? Color.BLUE : 0x646060);
        g.clear();
        super.paint(g);
    }

    protected void onFocus(int direction) {
        invalidate();
        super.onFocus(direction);
    }

    protected void onUnfocus() {
        invalidate();
        super.onUnfocus();
    }

    protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) {
        invalidate();
        return super.navigationMovement(dx, dy, status, time);
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        invalidate();
        return super.navigationClick(status, time);
    }

    protected boolean navigationUnclick(int status, int time) {
        invalidate();
        return super.navigationUnclick(status, time);
    }
};

final LabelField a = new LabelField("First Label Field") {
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
};

final LabelField b = new LabelField("Second Label Field") {
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
};

hrzMgrTimeLabel.add(new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE));
hrzMgrTimeLabel.add(a);
hrzMgrTimeLabel.add(b);
```

***Note***

`onFocus(...)`, `onUnfocus()`, `navigationMovement(...)`, `navigationClick(...)`, `navigationUnclick(...)` - these methods were just overrided for refreshing the drawing.

Comment: She simply asking to make manager focusable and other fields unfocusable in that manager. If Adding Null Field is only solution, then what is purpose of navigationMovement, navigationClick, here. Un-necessary Complex solution.

Comment: If you don't understand the purpose of `navigationMovement`, `navigationClick`, etc then you can ask an explanation, but how should you know that those are unnecessary? And adding focusable `NullField` isn't the only change made here. Read the code carefully.

Comment: Have you checked your code, if it is working as per requirements, and I know these methods are un-necessary, cause, these methods have invalidate in extra of super call, invalidate will invoke paint method again, but what does it changes into paint, isnt clear, cause focus is on NullField not on HFM.

Comment: Yes, I checked my code, and I think it is working. What do you think? Is it working or not? Actually I did check other codes also, for example the answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10979785/431639. When focus moves from `NullField` to other field on other manager, the manager that contain `NullField` must have to repaint all of it's field. And also the visual style is associated with the navigation click and unclick event. So it is also require repainting when any click and/or unclick event occurs.

Comment: If you think its working, then make a sample and try to execute that one. Study uses of NavigationMovement, NavigationClick, Managers and Fields, and Paint and other methods, and learn how to use them, further discussion over this answer would be waste of time, I think.

Comment: `Yes, I checked my code, and I think it is working. What do you think? Is it working or not?` - did you read those lines from previous comment. I didn't make any suggestion beyond my knowledge, and hope that you wouldn't. If you find anything irrelevant or wrong with the answer, specify what is it, and post some reliable link regarding that. And also execute the code before making comments.

Comment: `If you don't understand the purpose of navigationMovement, navigationClick, etc then you can ask an explanation` - I tried to explain, and realize that you didn't get it. If you have confusion, consult with someone who knows how to program, in BlackBerry specially. And also try to respect your own word, `further discussion over this answer would be waste of time, I think`.